# Not able to display sub menu in a separate block beside parent block

Tags: html, css

i have to create a nested menu but the problem i am facing is that the sub menu gets displayed inside the parent only with a horizontal scroll gets created(scrolling to extreme right you can see the sub menu)
currently the css i am using is

```
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  right: 100%;
  left: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g0kujLqk/

Comment: please recreate the situation in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) (or similar) otherwise the question is way too broad.

Comment: What class or id is this css applied? The JSFiddle is wrong

Comment: .category-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Refer on this Code:

```
  #templatemo_menu
{
clear: both;
width: 960px;
height: 50px;
background: url(../images/templatemo_menu_bg.gif) repeat-x;
   }


   #templatemo_menu ul li{
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

#templatemo_menu ul ul 
{
display: none;
position:absolute;
}

#templatemo_menu ul ul ul
{
left:100%;
top :-10px;

}

#templatemo_menu ul li:hover >ul
{
display:block;
padding:0;
margin-top:5px;
}
```